# Add a "Full Name" Field to Firebase Email/Password Authentication?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to add a "Full Name" field to the Email/Password authentication on Firebase? (Using Swift)

Comment: Do you mean the auth UI ? Or just generally adding metadata to a user?

Comment: @eikooc just adding the extra fields to database

Comment: You could store each user's account info along with their username, and then when they try to log in, see if their full name matches the one in your database associated with that password and email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add your own custom field to the Firebase Authentication social providers (Facebook, Google, etc) or email+password. You can of course store such information in your Firebase Database, keyed by the user's ID:

```
users
  uid_209103
    fullName: "Frank van Puffelen"
```

Note that Firebase Authentication already has a [`displayName` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/protocol_f_i_r_user_info-p#property-documentation) for each user, which may cover your needs.

Comment: How would you go about checking if a username stored in this way is taken?

Comment: I’m trying to implement email/password auth using firebaseAuthUI. On first login for new user it asks specifically for users full name but I cant seem to access it from the authUser data after login. Why would firebaseAuthUI ask a new email/password user for their full name but not make that full name available afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot add a new field in Firebase Authentication. However, you can still store a user's full name, Firebase does provide this facility. Either you can use Firebase Database to store a user's information as **Frank van Puffelen** stated in his answer above.

Or if you are just trying to save user's name, you can update User's profile (DisplayName and ProfilePhoto link). For iOS, [Update User's Profile in FirebaseAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#update_a_users_profile)

For Android, [Update User's Profile in FirebaseAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#update_a_users_profile)

It comes in handy when you have a basic app and you want to store only little information about the user such as their Display Name or Profile Profile only. What I do is, after creating a new user, update the user's profile immediately.