# How to set more information in FIRUser

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

I need more informations from FIRUser e.g. Name, LastName 
but I have no idea how to set this information into FIRUser.
Please can you guys suggestions.

I'm new in FireBase database

Comment: There is currently no way to add custom properties to a Firebase Authentication user. Most developers work around this by keeping the additional properties in a Firebase Database. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514008/add-a-full-name-field-to-firebase-email-password-authentication/37514477#37514477