# Overwrite data in fire base.

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xcode4, firebase-storage

Is it possible to overwrite user information in firebase? When the user signs up, they have to choose a profile picture, email, password and phone number. I would like to have users be able to edit all of their information, add a bio and have it save to fire base. I was wondering what code should I call in order to make this possible? Could I just copy the code from my signup screen and also add a bio? Would it over ride it? Or would it just create a new user

Answer (score 0):

There are only a limited number of properties that can be stored in a Firebase Authentication user profile.

For the list of properties that can be changed, see the [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/UserProfileChangeRequest). Right now that is limited to `displayName` and `photoURL`.

There is no property for storing the user's bio in Firebase Authentication, so you'll need to store that elsewhere. The most common places are in the Firebase Realtime Database or in Cloud Firestore. In there you'd create a node/document for each user, based on their UID, and then store the additional properties you want in there.

This topic has been covered quite a lot already, so I highly recommend you check out some of the [previous questions on storing user properties](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+store+user+properties), e.g.:

- [Add a "Full Name" Field to Firebase Email/Password Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514008/add-a-full-name-field-to-firebase-email-password-authentication/37514477#37514477)
- [Firebase: setting additional user properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415863/firebase-setting-additional-user-properties)
- [Add Extra Details on Firebase User Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038611/add-extra-details-on-firebase-user-table/41727216#41727216)
- [Adding new data to firebase users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657445/adding-new-data-to-firebase-users/46657503#46657503) (with even more links)